# Links that reload only a partial

Tags: hyperlink, typo3, partial

I have a partial in TYPO3 which contain links. I create them in a subroutine in my controller:

```php
    public function createLink($args)
    {
        $uri = $this->controllerContext
                    ->getUriBuilder()
                    ->reset()
                    ->setTargetPageUid($pageUid)
                    ->setAddQueryString(true)
                    ->setArguments($args)
                    ->buildFrontendUri();
        return $uri;
    }
```

This function does not create a relative link as I expected it. It should just reload the partial.

The only links that this function creates are of the following form

```
http://localhost/my-new-project/public/index.php?id
```

All options (ie. the controller context and the plugin) are missing. I expect that these links are local to the partial and reload only the partial when I click on them.

My TYPO3 Version is 9.5.13 on PHP 7.2.24 on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: be more specific with your problem (what do you get? what do you expect? and give some context so we can give you hints how to solve your whole problem in another way), and state the version of TYPO3

Comment: I builded my links the wrong way '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$pageNr.'</a>,' is correct. I exchanged ' and " before; that was my mistake. Unfortunately these links reload the whole page not only my partial as desired.

Comment: Only reloading a section of a page instead of the whole page, requires the usage of AJAX. which is not really a TYPO3 specific problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer.